# Reading map.txt from assets android

Tags: android, tilemap

I'm a beginner android developer currently working on my second app which is a platformer game. I'm trying to read the level map (which I've stored in the assets folder) but I keep getting a FileNotFoundException. This is the code to access it in the game play class:

```
@Override
public void init() {

    try {
        loadMap("file:///android_asset/map.txt"); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void loadMap(String filename) throws IOException {

    ArrayList lines = new ArrayList();
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    while (true) {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        // no more lines to read
        if (line == null) {
            reader.close();
            break;
        }

        if (!line.startsWith("!")) {
            lines.add(line);
            width = Math.max(width, line.length());

        }
    }
    height = lines.size();

    // Rest of the code
}
```

I have read about using `InputStream` but my game play class extends `State` rather than `Activity` so I'm unable to use it. Can anyone help me out on how I can access the file or how I can work around this problem, it'll be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23954878/file-android-asset-does-not-work), referencing the assets folder using the *file:///android_assets/* URI is only for WebViews.  You need to use *assets://* instead.

You should also be using the [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) to load your files.

EDIT: Poking around a bit further, you can bypass all of this by using the getAssets() method of your Context.  Store a reference to it somewhere and make it available to your game class.

Comment: Perhaps you can help me out a little bit, I'm very new to this. Could you explain this further please: store a reference and making it available to my game class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android Basically, the getAssets() method is available to your application Context, so you need to get the context (it's an object, so you get a reference to it), then store a variable somewhere in your game class that contains that reference so that you can access the context.  I suggested that because you said your game class didn't subclass an Activity.  If you don't understand object references, you need to read up on Java a bit more.

Comment: thanks, I managed to implement what you suggested. However, I got a new problem with bitmap and the game crashes. Maybe you could have a look at this and tell me what you think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32415478/load-tilemap-android